# Django query to retrieve rows that meet aggregate criteria on related table

Tags: python, django

I'm really stuck on a Django query and am hoping you've got a couple minutes to help me figure it out.

I have a very simple model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    # a tuple representing a specific item to be searched for a specific URL
    instructions = models.TextField()

ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ( 'a', 'assigned' ),
    ( 'c', 'submitted for review' ),
    ( 'f', 'finished' ),
    ( 'r', 'rejected' ),
)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    # the overall container representing a collection of terms for a page found
    # by a user
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='assignments')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default='a')
```

What I want to do is randomly select a task that has fewer than N assignments that are status != 'r'. In other words, I want to make sure each task gets successfully completed N times, so if a worker requests a task it needs one that has fewer than N tasks in a state that could lead to finishing.

I'm just totally lost trying to figure out the query that would return such tasks. For a given task, I can test:

```
task.assignments.exclude(status='r').count() < N
```

and if that is true it's a candidate. But how do I query Task.objects in such a way that it returns all candidates in a single database query such that I can randomly choose one:

```
Task.objects.<some magic filter>.order_by('?')[0]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you considered `Q objects`? They let you make more complicated query expressions -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I have, but I'm confused as to how I craft the Q object that does aggregation. I feel dumb when I say that, but I just can't wrap my head around it in this case.

Comment: ya I understand.  I'll be curious to see your solution!

Comment: as per the solution below, the trick is to add a virtual column "count" to the query and then filter on that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from django.db.models import Count

Task.objects.exclude(assignments__status='r').annotate(assignments_count=Count('assignments').filter(assignments_count__gt=N)

Comment: that was it, thanks! btw, you missed a paren:

    Task.objects.exclude(assignments__status='r').annotate(assignments_count=Count('assignments')).filter(assignments_count__gt=N)